# Authenticate Custom Content Block throws a CORS issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on, authentication, cors

I'm sitting up the SSO login for my application which is a custom content block by redirecting the user to the link below:

```js
var redirectRoute = "https://" + process.env.DEFAULT_BASE_URI + ".auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id="
  + process.env.CLIENT_ID + "&redirect_uri=" + process.env.APP_REDIRECT_URL;
  
router.get('/authenticate', function (req, res, next) {
  res.redirect(redirectRoute);
});
```

And this doesn't work due to a CORS issue:  `Refused to display (the redirect link) in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`

Any idea guys on how to fix this issue?